# Best way to clean up/shorten method with too many params & still enforce strict/non-missing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.0

I currently have a method with a lot of strict params that I want to shorten:

```
build_receipt(order_id:, order_rate:, ..... invoice_id:, invoice_date:...)
.
.
```

I'm thinking of grouping these up into hashes like so:

```
build_receipt(order_details: {}, invoice_details: {})
```

Would anyone know a sane way I can do the above while still throwing an error whenever a param is missing without explicitly having to write a validation for every key in the above hashes line by line (or if there is a better way the above method can be shortened)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue on from that and count the number of keys passed in, and that there are no missing values:

```
def build_receipt(order_details={}, invoice_details={})
  return if order_details.merge(invoice_details).keys.count != 5 or order_details.merge(invoice_details).values.any?{|v| v.nil? }
  #do something
end
```